# Is it possible for a group of order 132 to have 12 different subgroups of order 11?

Tags: group-theory

For me it looks like it isn't possible, but I can't see an argument. I've tried something with Sylow groups (consider all of them as Sylow 11-group and try to use Sylow theorems to find a contradiction), but unfortunately it didn't bring much.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I’m not any kind of group theorist, so I hope I don’t get egg on my face here. Look at those $12$ groups of order $11$. Any two of them can intersect only in the identity (otherwise they would be the same), so you have $12\times10$ elements of order $11$ in your group. This leaves only $12$ more: the identity and some elements of order $3$, $2$, and possibly $4$. Take any element $g$ of order $11$, and use it to conjugate and element $h$ of order $3$. If $ghg^{-1}$ is not $h$, then the elements $g^nhg^{-n}$ are eleven in number, eleven different elements of order $3$, leaving no room for elements of order $2\,$! So $g$ and $h$ must commute. Same argument for elements of order $2$ or $4$, so any element of order $11$ commutes with an element of order prime to $11$. This means the group is commutative after all, and then there is only the one subgroup of order $11$.

(I will defer to anyone that gives a less messy argumenent!)

Comment: You could also note that if there were 12 such subgroups then each one has to be its own normalizer by the sylow theorems.  But since your argument shows every Sylow-11 subgroup commutes with a non-Sylow-11 subgroup, we get a contradiction.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy, thanks. I’d been thinking bad thoughts about my approach till I saw your observation.

Comment: but why does it work with elements of order 2? we have 11 new elements of order 2 and they fit perfectly because 121+11=132?

Comment: Because then there are no elements of order 3.

Comment: But why do I necessarily need them, I put identity only once in the group though?

Comment: Cauchy's theorem says that if a prime $p$ divides the order of a group, then that group has an element of order $p$.

Comment: Oh, got it. Thanks a lot!